# Need to add a rule in Firebase DB

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to add a rule to limit the max int that could be saved in the `no_of_orders` field to `2`. The `OrderSchedule` document data is pre-populated via the app I'm developing.

Here is the `jsonExport` data.

```
    {
  "OrderSchedule" : {
    "13-Oct-2016" : {
      "13:00 - 14:00" : {
        "no_of_orders" : 4
      }
    }
  },
  "Orders" : {
    "-KTpIn4HeuDBDliCnTSA" : {
      "car_Model" : "Van",
      "date_Created" : 1476212105,
      "date_Scheduled" : "13-Oct-2016",
      "service_Type" : "Shine",
      "status" : "Scheduled",
      "time_Scheduled" : "13:00 - 14:00",
      "uid" : "sms|57f7b267e618d33da23e65ce"
    },
    "-KTpJ6BREc695pv4Ue6s" : {
      "car_Model" : "SUV",
      "date_Created" : 1476212188,
      "date_Scheduled" : "13-Oct-2016",
      "service_Type" : "Detailed",
      "status" : "Scheduled",
      "time_Scheduled" : "13:00 - 14:00",
      "uid" : "sms|57f7b267e618d33da23e65ce"
  },
  "users" : {
    "sms|57f7b267e618d33da23e65ce" : {
      "created_at" : 1475868493,
      "email" : "balouza@hotmail.com",
      "phone" : "+0000000000",
      "username" : "balouza"
    },
    "sms|57fa9701e618d33da240efa5" : {
      "created_at" : 1476040501,
      "email" : "look@hotmail.com",
      "phone" : "+00000000000",
      "username" : "bolzo"
    }
  }
}
```

Security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
      "max": {
        ".write": "auth != null"
      },
        ".OrderSchedule": {
          "$date": {
            "$timeSlot": {
              "no_of_orders": {
                ".validate": "newData.val() <= root.child('max').val()"
              }
            }
          }
        }
   }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of firebase db]

Comment: Provide your databaseJSON tree as text not snippet.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable requirement. What's the problem?

Comment: @Dravidian Here you go.

Comment: Please add your current security rules if you want to do this using the firebase security rules.

Comment: @AndréKool i didn't add custom rules yet. Here you are: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a parent node `key-value` pair in your Database.

```
{
   max : 2, 
   "OrderSchedule" : {
     "13-Oct-2016" : {
       "13:00 - 14:00" : {
         "no_of_orders" : 4
       }
     }
    },
    "Orders" : {
    "-KTpIn4HeuDBDliCnTSA" : {
      "car_Model" : "Van",
      "date_Created" : 1476212105,
      "date_Scheduled" : "13-Oct-2016",
      "service_Type" : "Shine",
      "status" : "Scheduled",
      "time_Scheduled" : "13:00 - 14:00",
      "uid" : "sms|57f7b267e618d33da23e65ce"
         },  
       ...

    }
```

In your security rules just add :-

```
  {
  "rules": {
   "max" : {
     ".write" : "false"
     },
    "OrderSchedule": {
      "$date":{
       "$timeInterval":{
          "no_of_orders":{
            ".validate": "newData.val() <= root.child('max').val()"
          } 
       }
     }
    }
  }
}
```

And if you want only the **authenticated users** to read and write in your database , use these :-

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null", 
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "max" : {
     ".write" : "false"
     }, 
    "OrderSchedule": {
      "$date":{
       "$timeInterval":{
          "no_of_orders":{
            ".validate": "newData.val() <= root.child('max').val()"
          } 
       }
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dravidian but why is it giving me this error: Key names can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]" (unbound names start with "$")...i even checked my syntax and curly brackets seems all fine. But it doesn't accept the $ sign. The strange thing is even when i remove it. Same error!!!

Comment: Can you update your question with your security rules. It has to be some sort of typo. And where do you get this error in your rules or your console?

Comment: Oh yes i found it its the ".OrderSchedule" Thanks @Dravidian